# how to pass data between a activity to dialogfragment

Tags: android, xamarin

I used this code to transfer data from Activite to the dialogfragment and did not work for me

How to send from Activite to dialogfragment. Once again, I reverse the process

```
//activity
  Bundle data = new Bundle();//create bundle instance
            data.PutString("key_value", "String to pass");//put string to pass with a key value
            dialogFragment.setArguments(data);//Set bundle data to fragment
//dialog
 var mArgs = Arguments;
            var myDay = mArgs.GetString("key_value");
            textb.Text = myDay;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-in fragment you access to actvity )so you can call any function from activity

```
 //in activty defien

  public string GetData(){

     return "datat";
   } 

 //in fragment call
 ((YourActivty)this.Activity).GetData();
```

2-another way use sharedprefrencess

```
//save in sharedPrefrences
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (context);
ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit ();
editor.PutString ("data", "my data");
// editor.Commit();    
editor.Apply(); 


//get datat
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (context);
String = prefs.GetString ("data","def value");
```

Comment: In the beginning, all thanks for the response. Would you please explain how to reverse the process and transfer a value from fragment to activity .

Comment: use shared prefrences..set data to sahred prefrenceess in fragment and  get that in activity

Comment: She tried and did not succeed with me  :var fragment = new DialogFragmentSample();
            ISharedPreferences prefe = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(fragment);
            ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefe.Edit();
            editor.PutInt("rating", 0);  // error in fragment

Comment: check my answer @ALIE